# Need a link to a form that will prepopulate some fields

Tags: url, parameters

specifically, below if the url to the form, is there anyway I can add parameters to this url so that the "referral field(name:programCode)" is prepopulated with "ref123"?

https://www.freecolorprinters.xerox.com/ApplyNowLink.do?method=fetchLookupValues

Answer (score 0):

Not just by adding parameters to the URL, but you can add code to either your Form, Action or by JavaScript to insert the values into the HTML.